# wrong flash-fill function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

let us suppose that we have following numbers in excel,generally flash fill is used to repeat formatting based on sample of formatting we give to excel, for example we have  6 digit numbers in excel

```
214567
343001
414571
333211
```

in excel i wrote following pattern

21-45-67

and used flash fill function to complete others formatting, but i am getting incorrect result

```
21-45-67
34-30-67
41-45-67
33-32-67
```

which seems definitely in correct, why?is there any rule or  why i am getting wrong result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Excel 2013's [Flash Fill¹](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Flash-Fill-9837EC4F-B45B-4C03-AF6D-FF900C202032) gets it heuristic guess wrong, supply an addition pattern example. In this case, B2 would be `34-30-01` to supplement B1's `21-45-67` pattern.

[image: Flash Fill Number patterns]

Now select B1:B4 and run [Flash Fill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoFill-and-Flash-Fill-2e79a709-c814-4b27-8bc2-c4dc84d49464).

[image: Flash Fill Multiple Number patterns]

---

¹ <sub>The [Flash Fill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-AutoFill-and-Flash-Fill-2e79a709-c814-4b27-8bc2-c4dc84d49464) command was introduced with Excel 2013. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>